# is there anyway to set swipe target width on "ons-split-view"

Tags: onsen-ui

Under ons-sliding-menu, you could set the attribute "swipe-target-width" to set the width of the swipable area . I wonder if one could do the same with "ons-split-view" (in collapsed mode ofcourse) as it could be used as sliding menu.

Answer (score 0):

I asked Onsen UI team. For now, you can't set swipable target area on split-view. It can't be done without modifying Onsen UI itself.